# Right usage of PHP isset

Tags: php

I would noramlly try to use the isset operator as below, where $x has to be forcefully set to null or $y if present

```
$x = isset($y) ? $y : null;
```

However below code does something similar. But, I am forced to write 'dummy'  code in the below solution. How can I prevent this?

```
isset($y) ? $x = $y: 'dummy';
```

Which solution #1 or #2 would be preferred?

Comment: This is a matter of preference, but I would _strongly_ prefer 1.  The ternary operator `cond ? true : false` is not meant to be used for flow control as your second example does. It is not really a shorthand for `if/then/else` and is typically used for assigning or returning values as your first one does.  For the second usage, `if(isset($y)) $x = $y;` is a more straightforward pattern, and the two aren't functionally equivalent because $x is left unset in the second.

Comment: I would use the first one since assigning variables inside the statement is weird and confusing.

Comment: I would like to emphasize this part: "$x is left unset" - so now the variable is *conditionally* set. Are you intentionally making your work harder?

Answer (score 1):

The principle which says that the "code is for programmers to read - and the binary is for the machine to read" applies here.

`$x = isset($y) ? $y : null;` is clean and straightforward

while

`isset($y) ? $x = $y: 'dummy';` is convoluted and oblique.

Comment: "Always code as if the person who ends up maintaining your code is a violent psychopath who knows where you live."